# Install powerline fonts on centOS6.6

Tags: fonts, centos6, vim-powerline, vim-airline

I installed recently [the patched fonts for Powerline users](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) from the github repository on a `centOS6.6` box.

As indicated in the [docs](https://github.com/powerline/fonts#installation) I executed the script that ran ok and printed

```
[statquant@latitude fonts]$ ./install.sh 
Copying fonts...
Resetting font cache, this may take a moment...
All Powerline fonts installed to /home/statquant/.local/share/fonts
```

And indeed:

```
[statquant@latitude fonts]$ tree /home/statquant/.local/share/fonts
/home/statquant/.local/share/fonts
├── Anonymice\ Powerline\ Bold\ Italic.ttf
├── Anonymice\ Powerline\ Bold.ttf
├── Anonymice\ Powerline\ Italic.ttf
├── Anonymice\ Powerline.ttf
...
```

But for some reason `gvim` is not picking up those fonts, as it the context menu `Edit > select font...` I have no trace on any `*Powerline` font.

Any help appreciated

Comment: add /home/statquant/.local/share/fonts to the font searching directory list. or just put those ttf files into /usr/share/fonts.

Comment: how do I add the path to the search list?

Comment: try /etc/fonts/fonts.conf

Comment: I have no root access

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html

Comment: Your suggestion of looking in the file was good, write an answer to get the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when adding fonts, one should put those fonts in the directory that fontconfig will scan. run `fc-list` to list available fonts.

[the fontconfig user's guide](http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html)

Comment: while you're at it I appears I have to change my terminal font from `~/.Xresources` I am using `terminal` (`xfce`), any idea what I need to put in this file to get a powerline font ?

Comment: Damn, so now I have it working on `gvim` but not vim, looks like it has to do with the terminal setup `terminal 0.4.7 xfce terminal emulator`

Comment: know little about xfce terminal,  in GNOME Terminal,  font can be modified by Editing Profile.

Comment: I think xfce terminal and gnome terminal are the same... almost. So there is a profile, `Edit>Preference>Appearance` but then the newly installed fonts are NOT in the list. Though I know it is there because when I open `gvim` I can see those fonts and can change them

Comment: run `fc-cache -f  -v` to update font cache, if still not work, restart terminal emulator.

Comment: you mean start a new terminal? or restart the desktop environment? It clearly did something as I see it printed "loaded 86 new fonts from my local dir", by they are still not in the terminal drop list choice menu

Comment: start a new terminal

Comment: This is crazy, `xfce` (the desktop) now sees the font, I can change all icon/window/... to use the new font... BUT when I start a terminal I cannot change the font within the terminal !! How sick is that ?

Comment: restart terminal emulator should work. So the last advice, logout then login.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it,
Looking in cat `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` I could see

```
<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>                                                                     
<dir>/usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1</dir> 
<dir>/usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF</dir> 
<dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
<dir>~/.fonts</dir>
```

Then I created a symlink `ln -s  ~/.local/share/fonts/ ~/.fonts`